# Separate part of script tag in DOM on loading page by regex

Tags: regex, laravel

I want to separate part of DOM that contain Javascript tag with variable named `matchData` that is a Object like below in laravel:

```
<div>
   some data
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var matchData = {
        sportId: 0,
        id: 80302,
        host: {
            id: 921587,
            name: "&#1606;&#1601;&#1578;&zwnj; 
        }
}
</script>
<div>
   some data
<div>
<script>
     ...
</script>
```

i want to get `matchData` value by regex.
i try this:

```
/\bmatchData\s*=\s*(.+)(?=;|<\/script>)/
```

but it just work when there isnt any new line or tab in the dom. how can i get `matchData` by regex?

Comment: Regex is *very poorly suited* to this task - please please consider using an XML parser instead!

Comment: it part of website that i try to crawle this. i get all html tag. i have to get this variable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex is not well suited to this task!** An HTML parser is a much, much better option. That being said, if you're dead-set on using regex, this may work: `var matchData[\s\S]*?(?=<\/script>)`

This starts matching at a var named `matchData`, and then continues matching until it hits the end of the first `</script>` tag. This solution is wildly inflexible and can be easily broken in a number of ways (such as if `</script>` is in the name), but if it's for a quick-and-dirty project and you don't care about maintainable code, it'll suit your needs.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL3Gch/1)